# How to load a owl file to neo4j using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, neo4j, load, owl

I have refered to this site "http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2009/05/using-neo4j-to-load-and-query-owl.html" for loading a owl file but having trouble in doing it. It shows  error at the import levl  . I have updated the library and jar files still the error persist.

Comment: can you give more details about the error you are facing, and also post your code so far? :)

Comment: the  import <org.neo4j.graphdb>cant be resolved etc

Answer (score 0):

Given that the referenced article is ~6 years old, I think it was based on Neo4j < 1.0. Don't remember completely but I think from 0.x -> 1.0 the package names changed, e.g. `org.neo4j.api.core.Relationship` moved to `org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship`.

So either figure out on which version the article was based and use that version or upgrade the code.

Comment: were can a find the  new package names

Comment: please give a alternative way to load a owl file to neo4j

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the required jars on the classpath.

Make sure you add all the jars you downloaded to your classpath.

Comment: I have added  all jars  related to neo4j and apache